# libconfig read list C

Tags: c++, c, list, configuration, libconfig

I'm trying to read this example of configuration with libconfig library in C, but don't see any example of reading a list and store it...

```
sound = {
         string_length = 50;
         sound_folder = "./bin/sound/";
         sounds_number = 4;
         sounds_list = ( "001_piano.wav", "voz4408.wav", "001_bajo.wav", "001_bateriabuena.wav" );
};
```

I what to know if there is a way to load a list like the sounds_list. And don't create a structure like the way I have it now:

```
 sounds_list = ( { file_name = "001_piano.wav";},
         { file_name = "voz4408.wav";},
         { file_name = "001_bajo.wav";},
         { file_name = "001_bateriabuena.wav";}
  );
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: The question is still not clear.

Comment: I whant to read sounds_list = ( "001_piano.wav", "voz4408.wav", "001_bajo.wav", "001_bateriabuena.wav" ); like a list and not like a struct and don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the structure as followed:

```
test_array = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];
```

when you want to parse the parameter above, you can use the code as followed:

```
libconfig::Config cfg;
cfg.readFile(conf_file.c_str());
const Setting &test_array = cfg.lookup("test_array");
int count = test_array.getLength();
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    std::cout << test_array[i] << std::endl;
}
```

you can also refer [libconfig_manual](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#Arrays) for more information